# Contact Form not working [PHP / AJAX]

Tags: php, ajax, phpmailer, contacts, mailer

When I test it I get a popup saying its submitting, but I also get a message from the ajax part saying there's an error, even though all the contents come to me by email successfully.

I think one problem is that there are two different submit messages coming from the both the PHP and the AJAX. Is the PHP needed then? The help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

The error message I get is the error response from the ajax after submit, saying "Error something wrong." I also get a pop up saying it was submitted correctly with is the echo from the PHP.

*UPDATE*********
Live Version: http://pieceofmedesigns.com/test/contact.html

Here is the AJAX:

```
$(function(){

$("#Submit").click(function(){

$.ajax({type:'POST', url: './php/mailer.php', data:$('#frmContact').serialize(), success: function(response) {
$("#spanMessage").html('Please Wait...');


 if(parseInt(response)>1)
   {
     $("#spanMessage").html('<div class="alert alert-success"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><strong>Well done!</strong> Your message has been sent.</div>');
   }
   else{
     alert(response);
     $("#spanMessage").html('<div class="alert alert-error"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><strong>Error! </strong> Somthing Wrong</div>');
   }


}});


});
```

Here is the PHP Mailer:

```
<?php session_start();
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
$youremail = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$fromsubject = 'Test Email';
$txtName = $_POST['txtName'];
$txtEmail = $_POST['txtEmail'];
$txtSubject = $_POST['txtSubject']; 
$txtText = $_POST['txtText']; 
$to = $youremail; 
$mailsubject = 'Masage recived from'.$fromsubject.' Contact Page';
$body = $fromsubject.'

The person that contacted you is  '.$txtName.'
 E-mail: '.$txtEmail'

 Message: 
 '.$txtText.'

|---------END MESSAGE----------|'; 
echo "Thank you fo your feedback. I will contact you shortly if needed.<br/>Go to <a       href='/index.php'>Home Page</a>"; 
                            mail($to, $subject, $body);
 } else { 
echo "You must write a message. </br> Please go to <a href='/contact.php'>Contact Page</a>"; 
}
?>
```

Here is the form:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="frmContact">
<h5>Whats your Name?</h5>
<input name="txtName" type="text" class="txbx" value="Name" /><br />
<h5>Whats your Email?</h5>
<input name="txtEmail" type="text" class="txbx" value="Email" /><br />
<h5>Email Subject?</h5>
<input name="txtSubject" type="text" class="txbx" value="Subject" /><br />
<div class="erabox">
<h5>Message to us</h5>
<textarea name="txtText" cols="" rows="" class="txbx era" value="Message" ></textarea>          <br />
<input name="" type="button" class="sendbtn" value="Send Message" align="left" id="btnSend"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't see in your form id "Submit"

Comment: can you please add the exact error message in your question? thank you

Comment: You also could place the button out of the form. By this you are sure there will be not submit by the form.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to name the button and make its id to `Submit`

```
<input name="Submit" type="button" class="sendbtn" value="Send Message" align="left" id="Submit"/>
             ^ // here was the mistake.                                                   ^ here also
```

the problem is here

```
if(parseInt(response)>1)
{
 $("#spanMessage").html('<div class="alert alert-success"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><strong>Well done!</strong> Your message has been sent.</div>');
}
else{
 alert(response);
 $("#spanMessage").html('<div class="alert alert-error"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><strong>Error! </strong> Somthing Wrong</div>');
}
```

the condition will allways fall to else part because you are using `parseInt(response)>1` condition.Instead use `true` `false` concept in `php` and check `true/false` in javascript.

Comment: Initially, I had the Submit in there, but it still failed, so I left it out because it seemed not to matter.

Comment: @Warren you haven't set the button's id to `Submit`. and calling the `Submit's` click event.Change it and try.

Comment: That script came with the template. What you mentioned is above my expertise lol

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#Submit").click(function(){}
```

instead of this line,

try

```
$("#frmContact").submit(function(){}
```

Please See [jQuery Submit Api](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) for more information. There is a similar example.